# How to find common value from a single table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
From this table

---------------------------
|  id        | country     |
---------------------------
|  1         | India       |
---------------------------
|  2         | India       |
---------------------------
|  2         | India       |
---------------------------
|  3         | India       |
---------------------------
|  1         | U.S.        |
---------------------------
|  1         | U.S.        |
---------------------------
|  2         | U.K.        |
---------------------------
|  2         | U.K.        |
---------------------------
|  2         | U.K.        |
---------------------------

i need to achieve this result

--------------
|  id        |
--------------
|  1         |
--------------
|  2         |
--------------

Scenario: I need to get the common id for country 'India' as well as non 'India'

Please, help me to achieve this.
```

Comment: what is your formula for "common", according to above data, common id for india = 2, and common id for non-india is also 2, why 1 is included in your list?

Answer (score 0):

try using IN

```
SELECT  id
FROM    mytable
WHERE   country = 'India'
        AND id IN ( SELECT  id
                    FROM    mytable
                    WHERE   country <> 'India' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select id
from
    (
    select id
    from CountryIDs 
    group by id, case when country = 'India' then 1 else 0 end
    ) ids
group by id
having COUNT(*)=2
```